# Is there a difference in speed between the controller and the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, performance, model-view-controller, load

If I'm defining a variable,  let's say `@x = (Page.all.count + User.where(default: true).count)`, is there any reason it would be faster to put that code in the controller rather than the view, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, Really not but if you put this in controller that would be great. Standards are to put all decisions statements in controller and let keep view clean I mean view should not contain any logic or db query.